# Incorrect dimensions after orientation change

Tags: android, orientation

I have a menu with a purple round action button. When I open the app in landscape the button has its correct margins at the top and right. When I open the app in portrait, and then rotate it to landscape, the button is a few pixels too high...

EDIT: it seems the button stays in the correct place, but the green background is shifting downwards... I added some extra XML of the background so maybe that helps to solve the problem.

Seems like a really strange bug to me...

Can anyone help me? If more information is needed, just ask!

How it is when I open the app in landscape (and how it should be!):
[image: How it should be]

How it is when I open the app in portrait and then rotate to landscape:
[image: This is wrong!]

Portrait mode (no problems):
[image: Portrait]

My landscape layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_panel"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionButtonSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionButtonSize"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/actionButtonMarginRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionButtonMarginTop"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/none"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

My dimens.xml in normal values folder:

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="actionButtonMarginRight">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="actionButtonMarginTop">100dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="panelHeight">128dp</dimen> <!-- the height of the green part -->

</resources>
```

The background:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" android:top="@dimen/panelHeight" ></item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Looks to me like the button is in the right place, but the background is shifting.

Comment: Mike M. is right. Button is staying at the same point but the Green backgound is becoming higher

Comment: Added some extra XML to the question so maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supposed to happen. When the screen orientation changes, Android restarts the Activity by sending onDestroy() followed by onCreate(). The startup sequence for the new orientation should be exactly the same as if the application had been started in that orientation.

It is possible that you have Java code that retains state across the configuration change. If so, we are trying to diagnose a problem in code you haven't shown us. Please show us the code.

If not, then it is something one of us might be interested in investigating further, but you haven't supplied enough code to do that. You should provide a Short Self-Contained Complete Example to demonstrate the problem, and not just an extract. See http://sscce.org/

If you won't or can't do either, then this question will probably be closed.